# How can I scale my Windows forms chart using the mouse wheel?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using windows forms chart control and this is the wheel mouse event:

```
void chart1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Delta < 0)
            {
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
            }

            if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                double xMin = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
                double xMax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;
                double yMin = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
                double yMax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;

                double posXStart = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) - (xMax - xMin) / 4;
                double posXFinish = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) + (xMax - xMin) / 4;
                double posYStart = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) - (yMax - yMin) / 4;
                double posYFinish = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) + (yMax - yMin) / 4;

                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(posXStart, posXFinish);
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoom(posYStart, posYFinish);
            }
        }
```

The problem is in the chart paint event when I draw points and connect them with lines when I use the wheel the points and lines are gone I don't think they are scaling right.

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2.5f);
        SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        private void chart1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            if (paintToCalaculate)
            {
                Series s = chart1.Series.FindByName("dummy");
                if (s == null) s = chart1.Series.Add("dummy");
                drawPoints.Clear();
                s.Points.Clear();
                foreach (PointF p in valuePoints)
                {
                    s.Points.AddXY(p.X, p.Y);
                    DataPoint pt = s.Points[0];
                    double x = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(pt.XValue);
                    double y = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(pt.YValues[0]);
                    drawPoints.Add(new Point((int)x, (int)y));
                    s.Points.Clear();
                }
                paintToCalaculate = false;
                chart1.Series.Remove(s);
            }
            foreach (Point p in drawPoints)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, p.X - 2, p.Y - 2, 4, 4);
            }
            if (drawPoints.Count > 1)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, drawPoints.ToArray());
            }
                    }
```

How can I take care in the wheel mouse event also about the points and lines I draw in the paint event ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to set your 'paintToCalaculate' flag when zooming.  It gets turned off during the first paint event and is not turned back on when zooming, so your lines are not being rescaled.